# RegExp: проверка Фамилии

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Нестандартность заключается в том, что нужно проверить фамилию, в которой могут быть украинские буквы. Например:

> `І і Ї ї Є є Ґ ґ`

Comment: Проверить на наличие чего?!

Comment: соответствует ли она шаблону

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста первый символ украинского алфавита в unicode-escape последовательности (`\u1234`) и последний символ алфавита. Так же на всякий случай дайте тоже самое, но в верхнем регистре.

Comment: эмм, пытаюсь загуглить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Составляйте обычное регулярное выражение, набирая первый и последний символ украинского алфавита.

```
$resourse='123sdafdsaЄds';
preg_match_all('/[Є-Їa-zа-я]+/iu', $resourse, $result);
var_dump($result);
```

Результат

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "sdafdsaЄds" } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно в регулярку дря русских букв просто добавить недостающие символы [/^А-Яа-яІіЇїЄєҐґ]